# SSL pinning with react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, ssl, ssl-certificate

Hi mobile experts,

I am working on an SSL certificate. I am running into a problem with the SSL pinning configuration in the mobile app (react-native).

I am using Network configuration for Android and App Transport Security Settings for IOS.

I got the certificate file with the .pem extension and it is successfully pinned for Android. The thing is IOS with a new configuration only accepts the hash key which is typically calculated from the certificate file.

When I am trying to pin the hash key, it is failing for both IOS and Android. Is there any need that the hash key also needs to be configured from the server-side?

This is the error I got:

*Text handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202*

Android doc: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-con...

IOS doc: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=g9ejcf8y

Hope that anyone has any good information for me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please share how do you get the hash and how do you make the fetch.

Comment: The solution I found is generated from public cert. But it does not work. Another solution is to generate directly which connects to the server-side. It might be something that need to be declared from the server if we use the hash key.